# This day in history VII

Tags: riddle, history

This day in history was solved first by Glorfindel with Yuzuriha Inori giving a more detailed answer. Today (9th May), a number of years ago, some sort of event happened. What was it and what do the clues mean?

> That wibbly-wobbly feeling
>   Like you get higher than a ceiling
>   A great psychological thriller
>   As complex as it is a winner
>
> Starring Ferguson and Madeleine
>   Played by James and Kim
>   A total 128 mins
>   One of the greatest of the Hitchcockian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it’s the release of the film

> [Vertigo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertigo_(film)) on May 9, 1958.

That wibbly-wobbly feeling
Like you get higher than a ceiling

> This describes vertigo, the condition

A great psychological thriller
As complex as it is a winner

> It’s a psychological thriller with initially mixed reviews but now known as one of Hitchcock’s finest films

Starring Ferguson and Madeleine

> The lead characters are James Ferguson and Madeleine Elster

Played by James and Kim

> James Stewart and Kim Novak, the lead actor and actress

A total 128 mins

> The runtime is 128 min

One of the greatest of the Hitchcockian

> A Hitchcock film

Comment: practically word-for-word as I would explain it. Well done!