# This day in history VIII

Tags: riddle, history

What historical event happened on this day (11th May). Can you explain the clues? Also, well done to El-Guest who got the answer to [This day in history VII](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98005/this-day-in-history-vii).

A man of great mind 
Bested by the first of its kind
It came from the people who *think*
And helped with financial modelling

After the deep
A new one they'd seek
And over 3 nights this machine
Wiped two champions clean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This refers to

> the chess computer Deep Blue beating chess world champion Garry Kasparov on 11 May 1997. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_versus_Kasparov,_1997,_Game_6) and [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXJMLoS-GCM).

*A man of great mind*

> Chess World Champion [Garry Kasparov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry_Kasparov).

*Bested by the first of its kind*

> [Deep Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer)), the first chess computer to beat a reigning world champion.

*It came from the people who think*

> Made by IBM whose slogan is [THINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_(IBM)).

*And helped with financial modelling*

> Did it? Or does this refer to IBM rather than Deep Blue specifically?

*After the deep*

> Deep ... Blue.

*A new one they'd seek

And over 3 nights this machine

Wiped two champions clean*

> Does this refer to [Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_(computer))? Not sure.

Comment: perfect! rot13(Lbh jrer evtug jvgu Jngfba. Nyfb, gurl hfrq Qrrc Oyhr'f cebtenzzvat gb uryc qrirybc fbzr svanapvny zbqryyvat fbsgjner.)